# RaspberryPI の　LANポートが点滅せず、SSH通信ができない。

Tags: raspberry-pi

RaspberryPI の　LANポートが点滅せず、SSH通信ができない。

こんにちは。
以前、VNC viewer , PuTTy を用いて　
raspberry <-> LANケーブル　<-> LAN usb変換アダプター <-> windows パソコン　
に接続して、SSH通信を行うことができました。

しかし、ここ最近、急にラズパイのLANポートのLEDの点滅がなくなり、通信ができなくなりました。windows上では、「ネットワークケーブルが接続されていません。」と表示されます。

LANケーブル、LAN usb変換アダプターの動作確認はしました。
ですので、ラズパイ側の故障だと思います。

どのように対処すれば良いのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

故障なら修理。
ってことになるわけですが、今どきの表面実装部品を使った基板の故障個所を見つけるのはその道のプロフェッショナルでもとても困難です。

手っ取り早く買い替えに１票。